# Using both CassandraRepository and ReactiveCassandraRepository in one Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-webflux, spring-data-cassandra

I'm working on a Spring Boot WebFlux application. The database I'm using is Cassandra and `ReactiveCassandraRepository` is primaraliy used to handle the database operations.

I need to add Spring Batch to my project to handle some long-running jobs. But Spring Batch does not support the reactive model. Due to this reason, I have devided to create two repositories for each entry using `CassandraRepository` and `ReactiveCassandraRepository`. Spring Batch will be using the standard repositories created by extending `CassandraRepository` whereas the other parts of the Spring Boot application will be using non-blocking `ReactiveCassandraRepository`.

Would it be an issue if I follow this approach? I'm planning to update the code and extend `AbstractCassandraConfiguration` instead of `AbstractReactiveCassandraConfiguration` to define the Cassandra configurations but I'm not sure If I should use both `@EnableCassandraRepositories` and `@EnableReactiveCassandraRepositories` annotations.

It would be very much appreciated if I could get some feedback on this. Specifically;

1. Is this appreciated correct?
2. How to use Spring Batch in a Spring Boot WebFlux application without having multiple versions of the repositories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a matter of configuration. You should be able to configure the two types of repositories and use the one you need in each part of the application.

That said, I would not mix both web apps and batch apps in the same application/JVM. Following the unix philosophy of making one thing do one thing and do it well, I would separate batch apps in their own JVM. This is cleaner IMO and would solve the issue by design.

Comment: Hi @Mahmoud Ben Hassine, thanks for the reply, and that makes total sense. Even I'd prefer to decouple the Batch project from the API project. But if I do that, then I will have to use a messaging mechanism to trigger a job from the API project and that's going to be additional work. I'd prefer to keep things simple as much as I can. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, you would make your API controller put a [JobLaunchRequest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/api/org/springframework/batch/integration/launch/JobLaunchRequest.html) in a queue to be picked up by a worker that launches your job. This is indeed a bit more work but a cleaner design IMO. Otherwise, you could always keep your jobs in the same JVM and launch them with local threads. That should not prevent you from configuring two repository beans (one reactive and one non reactive) and use the non reactive one for your batch jobs.

Comment: I believe I answered your question, so please accept it. Otherwise let me know what is missing to be accepted. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Mahmoud, thanks for the detailed answer. I have one more clarification - I'm using Spring Data Reactive Cassandra in a WebFux app. If I want to use Both reactive and non-reactive spring data repositories, should I use `AbstractCassandraConfiguration` or `AbstractReactiveCassandraConfiguration`. I tried using both of them and in both cases, both reactive and non-reactive repositories work with no issues. But I just want to double-check this. Also is it a must to use `EnableCassandraRepositories` and `EnableReactiveCassandraRepositories`? my code without works both of these as well.

Comment: Both are ok from my PoV. Choose whatever approach works for you.

Comment: Hi Mahmoud, sorry but your last reply isn't very clear to me. I'm working on a Spring Boot WebFlux REST API and it has Spring Batch as well. Since Spring Batch does not support, I want to use both reactive and non-reactive Spring Data repos. In order to do so, should I use `AbstractCassandraConfiguration` or `AbstractReactiveCassandraConfiguration`? also should I use `EnableCassandraRepositories` and `EnableReactiveCassandraRepositories` annotations? both reactive and non-reactive repos work with both of the configuration classes and also without any of the annotations.